# Lodash check if any object in array contains id match from another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have one user array like:

```
var users = [{
 id: 1,
 name: 'ABC',
 isDisplay: true
}, {
 id: 2,
 name: 'XYZ',
 isDisplay: true
}, {
 id: 3,
 name: 'JKL',
 isDisplay: true
}];
```

And another array selectedUsers which contains some object from above array like:

```
var selectedUsers = [{
 id: 1,
  name: 'ABC'
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: 'JKL'
}];
```

Not with lodash, i want to indentify which object are present in second array with matching its `ID`.

```
 _.each(users, (_u) => {
     if(selectedUsers.includes(_u)) {
       _u.isDisplay = false;
     } else {
       _u.isDisplay = true;
     }
  });
```

I have tried to match whole object with `includes` but it dint work, because i am using angularjs, so angular put some $$hashkey with object, so it will not match, Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Without lodash: `users.forEach(u => u.isDisplay = selectedUsers.some(su => su.id === u.id))`.

Comment: You just need to filter the array.

Comment: @Ved i need to set user's isDisplay false if id present in selecteduser.

Comment: @Tushar users.forEach(u => u.isDisplay = !selectedUsers.some(su => su.id === u.id)).. This works for me., just added ! before assigned value. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [{
 id: 1,
 name: 'ABC',
 isDisplay: true
}, {
 id: 2,
 name: 'XYZ',
 isDisplay: true
}, {
 id: 3,
 name: 'JKL',
 isDisplay: true
}];

var selectedUsers = [{
 id: 1,
  name: 'ABC'
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: 'JKL'
}];

var intersection = _.intersectionBy(users, selectedUsers, 'id');

console.log(intersection);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of selected ids (`selectedUsersIds`). Iterate the `users` array with [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), assign the value of `isDisplay` by checking if the `id` exists in the `selectedUsersIds` set:

```js
const users = [{"id":1,"name":"ABC","isDisplay":true},{"id":2,"name":"XYZ","isDisplay":true},{"id":3,"name":"JKL","isDisplay":true}];

const selectedUsers = [{"id":1,"name":"ABC"},{"id":3,"name":"JKL"}];

const selectedUsersIds = new Set(selectedUsers.map(({ id }) => id));

users.forEach((u) => u.isDisplay = selectedUsersIds.has(u.id));

console.log(users);
```